# image not displaying in java frame

Tags: java, swing, graphics, bufferedimage, drawimage

trying to learn windows programming in java, want to display a image to a frame.here is the problem code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("hello world");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(200,200);
        Graphics graph = frame.getGraphics();

        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("data/image.jpg"));
        graph.drawImage(image, 0,0,frame);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
```

i have seen some successful examples subclass the Component class and call the Graphics.DrawImage method in the paint method. why do you have to do that, can't you just grab the Graphics object associated with the frame and draw the image directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't because that's not the way Swing painting works. For one thing, painting has to happen on the [EDT](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html), and the preferred way to achieve this is overriding the `paintComponent(..)` method. Direct painting in the way you imagine is possible if you use [full screen mode](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/index.html), though.

Comment: This is correct and the right way to do it, another note is the function frame.getGraphics(), doesn't return anything until the frame is set to visible.

Comment: @Decad Oh, never tried to paint anywhere but in `paintComponent(..)` where I'm given a `Graphics` instance to play with. But good to know!

Comment: paintComponent() is the correct way to do it, i was just pointing out something in his code.

Answer (score 3):

No need for custom painting to show an image. See [How to Use Icons](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html).

The tutorial also has a section on "Custom Painting".